# Is the $2$-point function translation invariant for general Gaussian meaures?

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions, gaussian

Let us consider the real Hilbert space $H:=L^2\bigl(\mathbb{R}^n, \mathbb{R}^n\bigr)$ and "any" centered Gaussian measure $d\mu$ on it.

Next, denote a generic element of $H$ by the column vector $f(x)=\bigl[f_1(x), \cdots, f_n(x) \bigr]^T$.

Then, is it true that any $(ij)$-entry of the $2$-point correlation function for $\mu$, given by
\begin{equation}
C_{ij}(x,y):=\int_{H} f_i(x) f_j(y) d\mu(f)
\end{equation}
in facts depends on $x-y$ only?

That is, do we have
\begin{equation}
C_{ij}(x,y)=C_{ij}(x-y)
\end{equation}
for all $i,j=1,2,\cdots, n$?

I encountered such statements in the context of free scalar theories in QFT. However, I wonder if the property holds true in general.

Could anyone please help me?

Comment: the covariance matrix should be translationally invariant for this to hold; just saying that the measure is Gaussian is not enough, the translational invariance is an additional assumption

Comment: @CarloBeenakker    I see. Could you provide an example of a Gaussian measure on above $H$ wth translation-invariant covarince? For Schwartz space, I can set $-\Delta+1$, but I cannot come up with one on $H$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand\R{\mathbb R}$No, of course not. E.g., let $n=1$. Let $(B_t)_{t\in\R}$ be a standard Brownian motion. Let
$$\R\ni x\mapsto F(x):=B_x\,1(x\in[0,1]),$$
so that the random function $F$ is a centered Gaussian random vector in $L^2(\R,\R)$. Let $\mu$ be the distribution of $F$ in $L^2(\R,\R)$.

Then
$$C_{11}(x,y)=EF(x)F(y)=EB_x B_y\,1(x\in[0,1])\,1(y\in[0,1])\\
=\min(x,y)\,1(x\in[0,1])\,1(y\in[0,1]),$$
which is not a function of $x-y$.

---

More generally, if $G$ is any centered nonzero Gaussian random vector in $H:=L^2(\R^n,\R^n)$ with translation-invariant covariance, then $c:=\sum_{j=1}^n EG_j(x)^2>0$ does not depend on $x\in\R^n$. So,
$$E\|G\|_H^2=E\int_{\R^n}dx \sum_{j=1}^n G_j(x)^2=
\int_{\R^n}dx\, c
=\infty,$$
which contradicts [Fernique's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fernique%27s_theorem). So, there is no centered nonzero Gaussian random vector in $H:=L^2(\R^n,\R^n)$ with translation-invariant covariance.

Comment: Thank you for your concrete example. Could you provide a Gaussian measure on some $L^2$ space whose covariance is translation-invariant? Perhaps, is there a way to restrict the one on the space of distributions with covariance $-\Delta+1$?

Comment: @Isaac : I have added an answer to this question as well.